# Simplest graph that is not a segment intersection graph

Tags: computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Given a finite collection $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$ of straight-line segments in the plane, their *intersection graph* $G(S)$ is a graph that contains a vertex $v_i$ for each segment $s_i\in S$, and an edge $v_iv_j$ for every pair of segments $s_i, s_j$ that intersect.

Let us call a graph $G$ an *intersection graph* if there exists a collection of straight-line segments $S$ such that $G(S)=G$.

Which is the simplest (or a relatively simple) graph $G$ which is *not* an intersection graph?

(**Background:** Not all graphs are intersection graphs, since the number of $n$-vertex intersection graphs is only $2^{O(n\log n)}$ (can't find the reference right now), whereas the total number of $n$-vertex graphs is $2^{\Theta(n^2)}$.)

Comment: Any such graph must be non-planar, by Scheinerman's Conjecture : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinerman%27s_conjecture .  $K_5$ certainly isn't a counterexample (no $K_n$ is, obviously) and neither is $K_{3,3}$ (or any other $K_{m,n}$ - consider $m$ horizontal segments each of which intersects each of $n$ vertical segments).  Have you tried the Petersen graph?

Comment: OK. The Petersen graph is realizable.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a graph consisting of vertices and edges which would represent segments that are impossible in your geometry.

Consider an intersection graph with a set of vertices that contains eight elements $v_1$ through $v_8$. Let the edges be defined such that $v_1$ intersects $v_2$ and $v_8$, $v_2$ intersects $v_1$ and $v_3$, ... etc. Any geometric model of this graph must produce a closed eight sided polygon.

For each edge $e_{xy}$ in the graph, add five new vertices $w_{xyab}$ where $a$ and $b$ are the pairs of segments in the octagon that intersect, and $a \ne b \ne x \ne y$. Each $w_{xyab}$ intersects $v_a$, $v_b$, $v_x$, and $v_y$, but never any $w$.

I believe this is a graph that is impossible to model as intersecting coplanar segments. Proof to follow.

Comment: That particular example corresponds to a multigraph, which is not really a graph - or I assume that the OP is asking for a traditional graph.

Comment: Your example in the second paragraph does not work. If you arbitrarily lengthen the edges of the quadrilateral (but not the diagonal) the intersection graph remains constant, and then of course you can put another line in that intersects the existing edges. For instance, extend the non-diagonal edges to be infinite lines, then choose any diagonal line far away from the original quadrilateral.

Comment: Consider the following graph: It has a $K_4$ of blue vertices, and a $K_6$ of red vertices. Each red vertex is connected to by two edges to a different pair of blue vertices (note that $6=\binom{4}{2}$). This graph *is* realizable (how do I attach a picture?...). But what if we put *several* independent $K_6$'s connected to the same $K_4$? Or what if we use instead a blue $K_{10}$ and a single red $K_{45}$?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution: Take a nonplanar graph, say $K_5$. Add a vertex in the middle of each edge. We get a graph $G$ with $5$ "blue" vertices of degree $4$ and $5$ "red" vertices of degree $2$. I think $G$ is not realizable as an intersection graph of segments. If it were, we could obtain a planar embedding of $K_5$ by putting a vertex arbitrarily in each blue segment, and join the vertices to one another with piecewise linear arcs that go very close to the blue segments, and through the red segments.

Comment: Nitpickery: you get 10 red vertices of degree 2, not just 5.

Comment: Right. Thanks...